# Crash after GNOME customisation in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, crash

Using Chrome extension, I installed the Dash to Dock extension. Due to this
Dock overlapping (superimposition of two docks of different sizes) problem was also with 20.04, but in 22.04 it crashes too. It means the screen gets stuck (see the image below).

Dock freezes:

[image: dock freezes screen image]

Comment: If you suspect this is due to customization then please [edit] and describe the customization.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Dock is a fork of Dash To Dock, and actually uses the same settings. If you run both of these extensions, you see two overlapping docks.

Remove the Dash To Dock extension again. You can still customize it using `dconf-editor`.

Alternatively, disable Ubuntu Dock before enabling Dash to Dock.